# Reading a file from documents directory Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, filepath

I write a file to the documents directory of an app:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    // the path to write file
    NSString *file = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.json"];

    [responseString writeToFile:file atomically:YES];
```

But how can I access the file?

My code looks like this:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] pathForRessorce: @"data" ofType:@"JSON"];

    NSString *fileContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath]; 

    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

    NSDictionary *data = (NSDictionary *) [parser objectWithString:fileContent error:nil];
```

The file path is not populated...can somebody give me a hint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You are reading from resource folder, not from document directory. You need to populate `filePath` in the same way that you have used during writing. That is:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.json"];
NSString *fileContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Answer (score 2):

"initwithcontentsoffile is deprecated" warning

So Instead of:

```
NSString *fileContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

use:

```
NSString *userInfoFileContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```